# VB.NET Difference between a Class(Of OtherClass) and Class(Of T as OtherClass)

Tags: vb.net, class

The title is quite self explanatory. Both classes can be declared without errors, but I am certain they are different things.

Class(Of T as OtherClass) I know what it means and have used it a lot, but how is Class(Of OtherClass) different and when should one use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Public Class Test(Of T As OtherClass)` you are telling to the compiler that your generic type T must be "OtherClass", so when you use `Activator.CreateInstanc(Of T)` you will have the properties and methods of the class "OtherClass".

When you use `Public Class Test(Of OtherClass)` you are giving the name "OtherClass" for your generic type, so when you use the `Activator.CreateInstance(Of Type)` you will have the properties and methods of an Object.

Look at this example:

[image]

This compile error was rised because the clas "Type" is not an IEnumerable

When I remove the `As IEnumerable`:

[image]

The error is gone, because T can be any object.

Comment: Actually, not... I have updated the question to clarify its meaning, I meant to understand in generic terms what is the difference between declaring classes like that. Why is Activator.CreateInstance involved?

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. I was confused because of my poor choice of word, as Type is also the name of an existing .Net class. Could you edit your answer so that it uses OtherClass instead?

Comment: @UsuarioBeta I changed the answer, see you can you understand now..=P

Comment: @UsuarioBeta just to complete, we use it most with Interfaces os base classes like I posted in the pictures. So that you can use only classes that are implementing or inheriting your constraint.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, it is better to write these two examples of yours as:

- `Class(Of T)`
- `Class(Of T as OtherClass)`

`Class(Of T)` denotes a [generic `Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa0hwf23.aspx) that can accept any type for `T`.
It is legal to instantiate it as `Class(Of String)`, `Class(Of Integer)` etc.

`Class(Of T as OtherClass)` denotes a generic `Class` with a [constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4xaz66w.aspx). It can only accept types that satisfy the constraint (inherit from a certain type, implement a certain interface, have a public parameterless constructor, are reference types/value types).

I also find it a little bit strange that you are familiar with the latter but not the former. The unrestricted `Class(Of T)` is much more common. If that is not your experience, it might indicate that you are using generics where you should be using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create class(of otherType) at all!! and this is not useful 
for example this code is not valid:

1. Class test2(Of string)
2. End Class
   because string is a type name and cannot be a place holder for a range of types. 
   you should  constraint a generic type when you want to perform a spesific action on it. for example you want to create an instance of generic type:
3. Function createInstance(Of T As New)() As T
4. Return New T()
5. End Function
6. ...
   ...
7. myObject =createInstance(of object)()

and as you see "new" is not a class or type name but it supports any type that has a new method.
another example is when you want "T" be of any type that can be null:

1. Sub setToNull(Of T As Class)(obj As T)
2. obj = Nothing
3. End Sub
4. ...
   ...
5. setToNull(of object)(myObj)

so we restricted T to "class" that unlike structs and value types can be a nullable type.